# MySQL Group By makes some fieldds disappear

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

For the needs of my project, I need to display datas like this way:
Floor 1
Component1=> Area1
Component2 =>Area2
...
Floor 1
Subtotal Area =>Area1+Area2

---

Floor 2
Component3=> Area3
Component4 =>Area4
...
Floor 2
Subtotal Area2 =>Area3+Area4

---

total Area Subtotal1 + Subtotal2

---

But when I run this query:

```
SELECT `C`.`id` AS `componentID`, 
       `C`.`name` AS `componentName`, 
       `PC`.`id`, 
       `PC`.`_productID`, 
       `PC`.`_componentID`, 
       `PC`.`floor`, 
       `PC`.`area`, 
       SUM(PC.area) AS `AreaSum` 
  FROM `Component` AS `C` 
 INNER JOIN `Product_Component` AS `PC` 
    ON C.id=PC._componentID 
 WHERE (PC._productID= '79') 
 GROUP BY `PC`.`floor` ORDER BY `PC`.`floor` ASC
```

I dont get things as I expect. Instead of bringing list of fiels in the query and the SUM of areas by floor, I only got the sum of areas by floor.

And if I group by all field in the select list but not the Area, I got a repetitive list of area for each row in results.

Can you please help me to display datas as I descibed?

Below is my database structure:

```
`Component`

`id` int(11)             
`name` varchar(30)       
`dbname` varchar(100)   

`Product_Component`

`id` int(100)            
`_productID` int(11)     
`_componentID` int(11)    
`floor` int(3)          
`area` varchar(11)       
`details`  mediumtext
```

Comment: What you're looking for overall is probably `ROLLUP`, although I'm not sure if MySQL has this clause.  You may have to loop through all results in your application code and create this yourself.  Note that, every column not in an aggregate function (like `SUM(...)` or part of the `GROUP BY` will have a "random" value, something _you_ can't control.  Just about every other RDBMS will actually throw a syntax error if you tried this statement, because of this (it's really dangerous, because you get non-guaranteed results).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a part of looping in my code to display the Floor as title to have this:     
Floor 1  
---------------  
.......  
......  
Floor 2  
---------------  
.......  
......  
Floor 3  
---------------  
.......  
......  

What i need now is to display the sum of areas by floor